# What is a regular font?

Tags: writing

Here is the context: "Write your essay in a regular font".
What does it mean by "regular font"? What classifies as a regular font?
Thanks!

Comment: Best advice: ask your teacher.

Comment: It usually means not a custom font with idiosyncratic glyphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular font has no special treatments, such as italic or oblique, thin or bold. It is also not a stylized font, for example, Blackletter or Adventure.

Stick with a serif font like Times Roman, or a popular sans-serif font such as Helvetica.

Comment: I wouldn't write 'body copy' (like an essay) with a sans-serif font; I'd stick to non-monospaced serif-but-not-slab-serif fonts like your suggestion of Times, or Palatino, Bookman, Century Schoolbook, or any number of similar fonts that you might expect to see in a printed book.

Comment: I would disagree with the first sentence. A regular **font** does not preclude variants of that font. It might not even preclude fonts which are supplied with an operating system (like Comic Sans).

Comment: You have provided a description of *roman*, not *regular*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - You make a very good point here, though I would tend to believe that it means that the instructor does not, in fact, want fonts such as «spit» Comic Sans.